# Not able to store in datastore gcloud

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-datastore

I am learning golang and google app engine datastore.

I am planning on making a simple rest api call to save and retrieve data from the datastore.

I followed few hello world tutorials and the official get started guide. In the end what I came up with is this.

`

```
package hello

import (
        "fmt"
        "log"
        "net/http"
        "encoding/json"
        "cloud.google.com/go/datastore"
        "golang.org/x/net/context"
        "github.com/gorilla/mux"
        "time"
)
type Task struct {
        Description    string    `datastore:"description"`
        Created time.Time `datastore:"created"`
        id      int64
}
func saveData(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
        fmt.Println("Endpoint Hit: saveData")
        input := r.URL.Query().Get("input")
        fmt.Println(input)

        ctx := context.Background()
        projectID := "api-project-426361742627"
        client, err := datastore.NewClient(ctx, projectID)
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatalf("Failed to create client: %v", err)
        }
        kind := "Task"
        task := Task{
                Description: input,
                Created: time.Now(),
        }
        taskKey := datastore.IncompleteKey(kind, nil)

        if _, err := client.Put(ctx, taskKey, &task); err != nil {
                log.Fatalf("Failed to save task: %v", err)
        }

        fmt.Printf("Saved %v: %v\n", taskKey, task.Description)
        json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(task)
}
func returnAll(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
        fmt.Println("Endpoint Hit: returnAll")

        ctx := context.Background()
        projectID := "api-project-426361742627"
        client, err := datastore.NewClient(ctx, projectID)
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatalf("Failed to create client: %v", err)
        }

        query := datastore.NewQuery("Task").Order("description")

        var tasks []*Task

        keys, err := client.GetAll(ctx, query, &tasks)
        for i, key := range keys {
                tasks[i].id = key.ID
        }
        // for _, t := range tasks {
        //         // fmt.Println( t.id, t.Description)
        // }

        json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(tasks)
}

func homePage(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "Welcome to the HomePage!")
        fmt.Println("Endpoint Hit: homePage")
}
func handleRequests() {
        myRouter := mux.NewRouter()
        myRouter.HandleFunc("/", homePage)
        myRouter.HandleFunc("/save", saveData)
        myRouter.HandleFunc("/retrieve", returnAll)
        http.Handle("/", myRouter)
}
func init() {
        handleRequests()
}
```

`

Now the problem I am facing is at this line

`client, err := datastore.NewClient(ctx, projectID)`

I am getting the following error.

```
2017/09/26 07:15:16 http: panic serving 127.0.0.1:59488: not an App Engine context
goroutine 17 [running]:
net/http.(*conn).serve.func1(0xc82021e000)
    /home/aditya/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/goroot-1.6/src/net/http/server.go:1389 +0xc1
panic(0xa44740, 0xc82018a8c0)
    /home/aditya/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/goroot-1.6/src/runtime/panic.go:443 +0x4e9
google.golang.org/appengine/internal.fullyQualifiedAppID(0x7f4142e12be0, 0xc82000b4e0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /home/aditya/work/src/google.golang.org/appengine/internal/identity_classic.go:54 +0x8b
google.golang.org/appengine/internal.FullyQualifiedAppID(0x7f4142e12be0, 0xc82000b4e0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /home/aditya/work/src/google.golang.org/appengine/internal/api_common.go:77 +0xe2
google.golang.org/appengine/internal.AppID(0x7f4142e12be0, 0xc82000b4e0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /home/aditya/work/src/google.golang.org/appengine/internal/identity.go:13 +0x37
google.golang.org/appengine.AppID(0x7f4142e12be0, 0xc82000b4e0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /home/aditya/work/src/google.golang.org/appengine/identity.go:20 +0x37
golang.org/x/oauth2/google.FindDefaultCredentials(0x7f4142e12be0, 0xc82000b4e0, 0xc820222170, 0x1, 0x1, 0xc820222150, 0x0, 0x0)
    /home/aditya/work/src/golang.org/x/oauth2/google/default.go:92 +0x5a8
google.golang.org/api/internal.Creds(0x7f4142e12be0, 0xc82000b4e0, 0xc820248240, 0xc8202452c0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /home/aditya/work/src/google.golang.org/api/internal/creds.go:37 +0x173
google.golang.org/api/transport/grpc.Dial(0x7f4142e12be0, 0xc82000b4e0, 0xc820245638, 0x3, 0x3, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /home/aditya/work/src/google.golang.org/api/transport/grpc/dial.go:47 +0x272
cloud.google.com/go/datastore.NewClient(0x7f4142e12be0, 0xc82000b4e0, 0xc0c320, 0x18, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x9, 0x0, 0x0)
    /home/aditya/work/src/cloud.google.com/go/datastore/datastore.go:87 +0x87f
main76346.returnAll(0x7f4142dcb058, 0xc820234000, 0xc82022a000)
    hello.go:51 +0x1b8
net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP(0xcd13d8, 0x7f4142dcb058, 0xc820234000, 0xc82022a000)
    /home/aditya/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/goroot-1.6/src/net/http/server.go:1618 +0x3a
github.com/gorilla/mux.(*Router).ServeHTTP(0xc820052660, 0x7f4142dcb058, 0xc820234000, 0xc82022a000)
    /home/aditya/work/src/github.com/gorilla/mux/mux.go:133 +0x37c
net/http.(*ServeMux).ServeHTTP(0xc82000eab0, 0x7f4142dcb058, 0xc820234000, 0xc82022a000)
    /home/aditya/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/goroot-1.6/src/net/http/server.go:1910 +0x17d
appengine_internal.handleFilteredHTTP(0x7f4142dcb058, 0xc820234000, 0xc82022a000)
    /home/aditya/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/goroot-1.6/src/appengine_internal/api_dev.go:102 +0x409
net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP(0xccfe48, 0x7f4142dcb058, 0xc820234000, 0xc82022a000)
    /home/aditya/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/goroot-1.6/src/net/http/server.go:1618 +0x3a
net/http.serverHandler.ServeHTTP(0xc820078500, 0x7f4142dcb058, 0xc820234000, 0xc82022a000)
    /home/aditya/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/goroot-1.6/src/net/http/server.go:2081 +0x19e
net/http.(*conn).serve(0xc82021e000)
    /home/aditya/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/goroot-1.6/src/net/http/server.go:1472 +0xf2e
created by net/http.(*Server).Serve
    /home/aditya/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/goroot-1.6/src/net/http/server.go:2137 +0x44e
INFO     2017-09-26 07:15:16,800 module.py:821] default: "GET /retrieve HTTP/1.1" 500 3349
```

I am not sure how to go about fixing this issue. I tried using

```
gcloud auth application-default login
```

to give access to the datastore locally but it is not working. Whenever I try to save the data or return all entries while initializing the datastore new client I am facing this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your handlers to use a context derived from app's handler request instead of `context.Background()`

```
func saveData(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
    // ..
    fmt.Println(input)

    ctx := appengine.NewContext(r)
    projectID := "api-project-426361742627"
    // ...
}
```

Remember that context can be used as an opaque value container as well and app engine environment makes heavy use of this feature.

Package [appengine docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/reference#NewContext).